# Application closing unexpectedly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an application in android and using BroadcastReceiver class to override the method onReceive. But my application is closing unexpectedly when an SMS comes. The code is shown below.

```
package com.jb.blinkme;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BlinkMe extends Activity {

private static final int LED_NOTIFICATION_ID = 33;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blink_me);
    RedFlashLight();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_blink_me, menu);
    return true;
}
public void RedFlashLight() {
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.ledARGB = 0xF7FE2E;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 1000; 
    notif.ledOffMS = 1000; 
    nm.notify(LED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(mClearLED_Task, 10000);
}
public void ClearLED() {
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    nm.cancel( LED_NOTIFICATION_ID );
}
public Runnable mClearLED_Task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ClearLED();
    }
};

}

package com.jb.blinkme;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

/**
 * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    BlinkMe blink = new BlinkMe();
    blink.RedFlashLight();

}
}
```

and my manifest file is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jb.blinkme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <activity
        android:name=".BlinkMe"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_blink_me" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

But while running the application, It is closing unexpectedly and I am getting the following error from LogCat.

```
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.jb.blinkme.SMSReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2146)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3989)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at com.jb.blinkme.BlinkMe.RedFlashLight(BlinkMe.java:32)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at com.jb.blinkme.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:18)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2139)
10-10 23:38:53.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6248):     ... 10 more
```

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BlinkMe blink = new BlinkMe();
blink.RedFlashLight();
```

That is wrong in your `onReceive`. You can't create an instance like this for `Activity` since it is not a `Class`.

Comment: Do you want to perhaps suggest how the OP should fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the application is closing even if I keep the onReceive method empty.

Comment: Okey, when do you call your broadcast?

Comment: As I am new to android, I am not aware of that. Can you please advice me?

Comment: Try to create SMS Receiver as a separate class and not as a inne class inside the Activity.

Comment: I think that is causing the crash, because it doesn't find that

Comment: hm.. and it crashes even when is empty? let me check and I'll come back to you.

Comment: Your Manifest looks good, though I don't know why you would use android:enabled"true"

Comment: And the application is developed for ICS.

Comment: I was just trying all possibilities. Found that from some where.

Comment: Actually, everything looks good. Try to clean and rebuild project with nothing inside onReceive and see if still crashes with same error.

Comment: Okay. I will check and get back to you soon.

Comment: there's your error: at com.jb.blinkme.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:18) at line 18 in your SMSReceiver.

Comment: Now the application is not crashing :) :) Then can you please let me know that, how can I call the function in activity from my onReceive function?

Comment: Well mate, you should not call one Activity method outside of the Activity. So for the simplicity, just copy the method from your Activity into your SMSReceiver class, and call it there as a normal call.

Comment: Hey Carnal, As I am using NotificationManager class in my method, it is not possible to declare that method inside SMSReceiver class. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes it is totally possible, you need to use context.getSystemService. When calling from Activity, context is not needed :)

Comment: And you have the context in onReceive ;) use that one!

Comment: Great mate, I'm going to sleep now. Good night =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
BlinkMe blink = new BlinkMe();
blink.RedFlashLight();

Do:
BlinkMe.RedFlashLight()

and be sure to make that method static (try making the varaiable static)